# How do I get Images to work in email sent via rails mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've read a few questions here on SO that explain this process, I can't seem to get them to work. Simply trying to embed and image into an email send via mailer.

The email comes through just fine, the image is missing.

Here's my helper.

```
  def new_request(email, row)
    @candidate = row
    attachments.inline["logo01.png"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo01.png")
    mail(to: email, subject: 'New request')
  end
```

and then here's my view

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo01.png'].url %>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you set the `asset_host` in your development.rb? It should look something like the following `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'` and by default *image_tag* reads from `assets/images` path

Comment: I have set the asset_host in dev.rb exactly as you suggested. Didn't do the trick, and what do you mean by 'by default image_tag reads from assets/images path' is there something else I should change in regard to that latter point?

Comment: Change `#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/logo01.png` to `#{Rails.root}/assets/images/logo01.png`